# Dates in php Sunday and Saturday?

Tags: php, date

i have one date.

example : `$date='2011-21-12'`;

data format :yyyy-dd-mm;

IF date is Saturday or Sunday.

if Saturday add 2 day to the given date.

if Sunday add 1 day to the given date. 
?

Comment: can u explain what is the exact format ? is `YYYY-DD-MM`?

Comment: if((today+1).isSaturday()) { echo "yeahhh!"; } :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a single line of code:

```
if (date('N', $date) > 5) $nextweekday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next Monday", $date));
```

If the day of week has a value greater than 5 (Monday = 1, Sat is 6 and Sun is 7) set $nextweekday to the YYYY-MM-DD value of the following Monday.

Editing to add, because the date format may not be accepted, you would need to reformat the date first. Add the following lines above my code:

```
$pieces = explode('-', $date);
$date = $pieces[0].'-'.$pieces[2].'-'.$pieces[1];
```

This will put the date in Y-m-d order so that strtotime can recognize it.

Comment: Nice, didn't go for the obvious strtotime().

Comment: `create_date_from_format()` instead of strtotime would solve the pre-parsing and still give you functions for "next monday"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [date](http://php.net/date) and [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) functions for this, like so:

```
$date = strtotime('2011-12-21');
$is_saturday = date('l', $date) == 'Saturday';
$is_sunday = date('l', $date) == 'Sunday';

if($is_saturday) {
    $date = strtotime('+2 days', $date);
} else if($is_sunday) {
    $date = strtotime('+1 days', $date);
}

echo 'Date is now ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
$date='2011-21-12';

if (date("D", strtotime($date)) == "Sat"){
   $new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 2 days",$date);
}

else if (date("D", strtotime($date)) == "Sun"){
   $new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day",$date);
}
```

Comment: This won't work because of the format of the date... strtotime will return false when passed '2011-21-12'.

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime object can be really helpful for anything like this.
In this case.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', '2011-21-12');
if ($date->format('l') == 'Sunday')
    $date->modify('+1 day');
elseif ($date->format('l') == 'Saturday')
    $date->modify('+2 days');
```

If you want to get the date back in that format.

```
$date = $date->format('Y-d-m');
```

Comment: Note that this only works with PHP 5.3 (which everybody should use).

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '2011-21-12'
$stamp = strtotime($date);
$day = date("l", $stamp);
if ($day == "Saturday"){
    $stamp = $stamp + (2*+86400);
}elseif($day == "Sunday"){
    $stamp = $stamp + 86400;
}
echo date("Y-d-m", $stamp);
```

The only reason i can think why this wouldnt work is strtotime not recognising that data format...

Answer (score 0):

For sundays date('w',$date) will return 0, so the simplest test code is:

```
if(!date('w',strtotime($date)) { ... } //sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

I just subtracted the difference from 8 an added it to the days.

```
if(date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) {
        $n = (8 - date("N",strtotime($date)));
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$n." days");
}
```